How can I find what is driving the change between my updated model and the original model?
I'm working on updating a model of rents (which is currently simple OLS) for my employer who has a large national portfolio. By tweaking here and there and drawing in a large amount of exogenous data to account for the "neighborhood" factor in finding a place to live I've seen some modest improvements in R-squared, AIC, MSE and the typical metrics.
However, my boss was quick to point out that we need to inspect it at the regional and community level as well. Part of that is a black box to me since he's applying fairly deep expert knowledge of our employer's portfolio, and often qualitative assessments. But from what I've seen of the model validation analysis I conducted (which mainly looks at MSE within each community), at the community level there are some winners, some losers but more winners than losers and the decrease in MSE for the winners was more extreme than the increase for the losers. What's perplexing to me though is the seeming randomness of who benefits from the new model. Looking at a map, there are a couple of clusters of decrease in MSE and a couple cluster of increase in MSE. But for the most part a community with a large decrease can be right next to one with a large increase. When I pulled two slices of the dataframe, one for the 20 biggest winners and one for the 20 biggest losers, the two looked about the same. Same modal region, similar average sf, similar average home age, number of homes in the community, every one of the primary metrics looked similar. But the changes in predicted rent were at times extreme.
It should be noted, the original model followed this pattern as well, it just looks very different.
So my question is, what can I do to determine what is driving the change so as to inform my future model tweaking efforts? Optimally I'm looking for a method where I can look at a community and have it tell me "variables X,Y,Z are primarily responsible for the change in predicted rent to A,B,C extent". But TBH anything that would give me any sort of insight here would be a godsend.
TIA!

Your data seems to be hierarchical (individuals nested within communities nested within regions, etc.) so a multilevel model, such as linear mixed-effects regression, would be a better approach than simple OLS regression. Observations that are within the same community or region are likely correlated which could be why you see a clustering pattern in the MSE.
In a multilevel model, these can be specified as random effects (either intercept or slope) to account for this. These models can also allow you to estimate group effects.
However, you should still check similar model assumptions for mixed-effects regression as you would for simple OLS (linearity, normality of residuals, homoscedasticity).
Here's more info on multi-level models

Thanks so much for your input. I 100% agree with you in theory, but I've mapped the data extensively and there doesn't seem to be much impact from geography. Dallas as an example, there's probably 30 communities there and there's no real trend in terms of MSE. It's just a mixed bag of most minor positive or negative changes in MSE with a handful of extreme ones. There are a few instances of geographical clusters but they are the exception to the rule. Do you think I should be looking at multilevel models anyway?
